# Calling methods in main thread from other threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am trying to run 3 levels of timers at the same time in a C# application
for example:

T1 will run in the beginning of the application, then on its Tick event, T2 will start
and then on the tick event of T2, T3 will start.
Finally, on the tick event of T3, something should be  done in the main thread of the application

My problem seems to be that the code in the main thread is not working when it is being called by an other thread

What should I do to let the main thread run its functions by a call from other threads?

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: What is the **business* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Class C1
{
Timer T1;
C2 c2;
OnT1Tick()
{
c2.T2.start()
}
}

Class C2
{
Timer T2
C3 c3;

OnT2Tick()
{
c3.T3.start
}
}

Class C3
{
Timer T3

OnT3Tick()
{
system.console.write ("something");
}
}

The problem is that the system.console.write is being called from the main thread and each timer is creating a new thread

Comment: @user2302005 please edit your question and copy/paste the code from the ide. nowhere i see `new` keyword. are you sure even the first timer is firing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Most probably the problem is that your main thread requires invocation. If you would run your program in debugger, you should see the Cross-thread operation exception, but at run time this exception check is disabled.

If your main thread is a form, you can handle it with this short code:

```
 if (InvokeRequired)
 {
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => MyFunction()));
    return;
 }
```

or .NET 2.0

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {MyFunction();});
```

EDIT: for console application you can try following:

```
  var mydelegate = new Action<object>(delegate(object param)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(param.ToString());
  });
  mydelegate.Invoke("test");
```

Comment: Actually, at last, it will be a unity3D function
But currently I am working on the classes

Comment: VS 2013/Resharper 8 tells me I can simpify this to this.Invoke(new Action(MyFunction));

Comment: @VladL The console app part, of the delegate thingy doesn't work for me. I defined that variable in a class as static, and I invoke It from a timer, but the Thread is still not the main thread.

Comment: Help please, It is really needed.

Comment: @DreTaX ask the new question, it's hard to help without seeing the code

Comment: Oh wel.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770367/c-sharp-call-methods-from-main-thread?noredirect=1#comment61118198_36770367  will include it

Comment: @VladL: this `Invoke` method, where does it belong to? which class? MSDN please?

Comment: @knocte long time ago... but should be Control.Invoke as the method is directly available on the windows form

Comment: System.Windows.Forms?