# How can i freeze the dialog if when it is not having proper parent?

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

I want to freeze reminder pop up dialog, it popes up once timer completes. But it goes in background. I want to freeze it and show it to top. I am not able to figure out how can i do that?

As i don't have parent i am stuck to freeze this reminder dialog.

```
 ReminderTask(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);   
 m_schedulePHCheckAndCleanReminderDlgThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowSchedulePHCheckAndCleanReminderDlg));
 m_schedulePHCheckAndCleanReminderDlgThread.Start(); 

 private void ShowSchedulePHCheckAndCleanReminderDlg()
 {
 m_schedulePHCheckAndCleanReminderDlg.ShowDialog(); 
 }
```

Comment: You need to call ShowSchedulePHCheckAndCleanReminderDlg from the main thread, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123061/calling-methods-in-main-thread-from-other-threads

Comment: You cannot create, update or even interact with any UI element on any thread other than the UI thread. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Actually i don't want to run in main thread because it will slow the system. is there any other way?

Comment: hi Enigmativity,
Actually i want to show the reminder dialog once timer completes, That should on top, currently it is going in background as other dilogs are not blocked.